# C++ <-> Python: bidirectional communication

Tags: python, c++, embedded-language

I want to integrate a Python application into my C++ application. The communication has to be bidirectional, as shown in the following example:

C++:

```
void main() {
    # call python code

    return 0;
}

int computeResult(int value) {
    int result;
    // do stuff with value
    return result;
}
```

Python:

```
def run(value):
    result = computeResult(value)    # call computeResult of C++ code
    ...

for i in xrange(0, 10):
    run(i)
```

I thought about calling the Python code from C++ via embedded Python, but I don't know how I can call computeResult from my Python code. I don't want to create a new process everytime I call computeResult, so I would have to access the existing instance of my C++ application.

Any ideas would be appreciated, even if they don't use embedded Python.

Comment: You can write an extension over your C function to make it available in python.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Would that create a new process every time I call the computeResult function from my python code?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html this might be useful

Comment: No, that doesn't create a new process. Basically you would need to write a python extension equivalent of your C method in C using PyObject* kind of things. Then, you can make a shared library of the same and import that module in python. Then, its just like using any other module in python. The link given by Michael would be useful.

Comment: I took a look at the link Michael posted. The paragraph [link](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html#extending-embedded-python) seems to do exactly was I was trying to do. Thanks again to both of you!